# After two or more screen rotations, lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated stops working as expected

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I have a code like this:

```
    private val appViewModel: AppViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var user: User

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // This sets the variable user to the value collected from a StateFlow from appViewmodel 
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            appViewModel.user.collect { flowUser -> user = flowUser }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        
        // This method utilizes the lateinit user variable
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            doThingWithUser()
        }

        return binding?.root
    }
```

Since the value of *StateFlow* persists even after being collected, after the screen rotates the first `lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated` gets called, collects the **flowUser** from the *flow* again, assigns it to the lateinit `user` variable, and `doThingWithUser` gets called later and everything works fine.

But after two or more rotations, this stops being the case, for some reason `user` doesn't get initialized, `doThingWithUser` gets called and the app crashes with **kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException**.

What am I doing wrong? Does the value from *StateFlow* vanishes after two collections/screen rotations? Something happens with the actual *flow* inside the *ViewModel*? Something happens with the `onCreate` and `onCreateView` methods? Or does `launchWhenStarted` and `launchWhenCreated` behave differently after two rotations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. Apparently the Navigation Component messes with the order of the fragment's lifecycles, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157241/fragment-lifecycle-overlap-on-navigate).

So when the screen rotated, due to the backstack order, the Navigation was creating another fragment that also interacts with the *StateFlow* of the *ViewModel* before the current Fragment. So, the other fragment `onCreate` method was sending something else to the flow, and therefore messing my current fragment collection.

The solution is to either make the flow collection independent of the fragment lifecycle, or change the collection in either one of the trouble fragments.

Comment: Reordering transactions as mentioned in that other issue has *no* impact on what order fragments go through `onCreate()` after a configuration change.

Comment: So it's just random?

Comment: It is in the exact order you add fragments to the FragmentManager, completely deterministic.

Comment: What if I set my navigation with nav_graph?

Comment: Navigation doesn't change the order fragments are added - they're added in the order you navigate to them in.